# Error with Condor: "$INT() macro: 50+ $((0/41)) does not evaluate to an integer!"

Tags: shell, condor

I want to run several jobs with Condor, my executable take as an argument `b` such that: `b1=50+ $(($(Process)/41))`, where `$(())`stands for the  quotient of `$(Process)` divided by 41. `b` is defined in `quotient.sh`. Here is my submit file:

```
    # Unix submit description file
include : PATH/quotient.sh
executable              = PATH/script_test.sh
arguments               = $(b) $(Process)
log                     = fit_it_data_$INT(b)_$(Process).log
output                  = outfile_fit_$INT(b)_$(Process).txt
error                   = errors_fit_$INT(b)_$(Process).txt
transfer_input_files    = PATH
should_transfer_files   = Yes
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT
queue 81
```

However I am getting the error `Submitting job(s)ERROR at Queue statement on Line 13: $INT() macro: 50+ $((0/41)) does not evaluate to an integer!`. I don't understand why it complains that is does not evaluate to an integer, since b should be equal to 50 here...
Any idea how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
b1=50+ $(($(Process)/41))
```

I think you have an extra "$" in there.  Try this:

```
b1=50+ ($(Process)/41)
```